# Sidebar Cart in Magento doesn't work properly

Tags: magento, cart

I have a sidebar cart on a magento store i am working on. It has been moved to the bottom of the site. 
I have been able to show how many items are in the cart in the footer (footer is located within header.phtml), however, when you hover over the cart, it tells you that there is nothing in the cart. I have added an extension that uses Ajax to add items to the cart. When you add items to the cart, the sidebar cart then works properly, and displays the products that are currently in the cart. However, when you refresh the page, this stops working and 'nothing is in the cart'. Any ideas as to what would cause this?

The web address is

[eds.beadmansolutions.co.uk](http://eds.beadmansolutions.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

Hello please add this code on checkout.xml

```
<default>
<reference name="footer">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_footer" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

call on footer.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar_footer') ?>
```

Comment: This has just broken my cart completely now. I have reverted back to my previous code, which had all this already, except the reference name was 'right', and the cart still doesnt work, even when you go to checkout. Nothing is shown

Comment: Managed to get the checkout/cart working again. still nothing on the sidebar cart front though. Still doesnt display products unless i add them to the cart and then hover.